# How to set images from TextBox to Image list or PictureBox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a button which browses files into TextBox (image files) and I need to insert these files into imagelist (or/and) PictureBox. I know how to do that other way for example ImageList -> choose Images, but I need to get images from TextBox (where is that location). Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can load the image directly into a PictureBox using the Load method

```
myPictureBox.Load("c:\temp\test.jpg")
```

You can load the image to the imagelist using Image.Add method

```
ImageList1.Images.Add(New Bitmap("c:\temp\test.jpg"))
```

Comment: It works fine with one image but I need to do this task with multiple images (I wrote TextBox2.text insted of  `c:\temp\test.jpg`) but it crashes when  I browse more then one image into the TextBox2

Comment: What error do you get, and how do you have more than one image path in the textbox?